# Relative URL or using _spPageContextInfo

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, 2016, custom-javascript, relative-path

For some reason, relative URLs are not working OR I am using the wrong syntax.  I have tried the following with no luck on my CEWP HTML page.

```
<script src="/jslib/jquery351/jquery351.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jslib/jquery351/jquery351.min.js"></script>
<script src="/../jslib/jquery351/jquery351.min.js"></script>
<script src="/.../jslib/jquery351/jquery351.min.js"></script>
<script src=".../jslib/jquery351/jquery351.min.js"></script>
<script src="~jslib/jquery351/jquery351.min.js"></script>
```

I was thinking of using the _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl function but I'm having issues implementing it into the HTML page to dynamically create the src string dynamically and having absolute URLs for test and production is getting old.

In a previous job, these worked so I'm wondering if this is a server setting out of curiosity.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this <script src="../../jslib/jquery351/jquery351.min.js"></script> also  please share sample for the current URL in address bar to can specify the relative path (don;t add the real url, just sample)

Comment: well, I thought I had tried that one frankly but looks like I didn't because it is working now.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script src="../../jslib/jquery351/jquery351.min.js"></script>
```